# JavaScript: CSS Selection Syntax

Tags: javascript, html, css

what is the best syntax to follow when wanting to select elements in a syntax similar to CSS.

For example consider the following, if I wanted the text inside `.selector` to be red:

```
<div class="selector">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

In css I would do this:

```
.selector p {
  color:red;
}
```

If wanted to use the same kind of CSS selection tree with JavaScript, I would do this:

```
var selector = document.querySelectorAll('.selector p');    
for (i = 0; i < selector.length; ++i) {
  selector[i].style.color = "red"
}
```

This seems to be the best way of following a CSS based syntax when working with JavaScript and using a selection tree.

Is there a better way of doing things or is this considered best practice?

EDIT - No jQuery please. Unless you're explaining how jQuery's back-end syntax works in achieving the the same thing.

Comment: Define what do you mean better? Readability? Speed? Memory?

Comment: Typically it's better to append a class for styling elements, rather than directly manipulating the style attribute.

Comment: And if you are going to modify the style of the elements, consider removing them from the DOM first (it might be good enough to set `display: none`, but I'm not 100% sure), and then add them back in when the changes are finished.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding. The element styling/adding a class isn't the point. I've just used it as an example to show CSS selection.

Answer (score 3):

This is best practise if you don't need to support legacy browsers like Internet Explorer version 6, 7 or 8.

What most people do instead is use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to allow them to use CSS selectors in all browsers. On modern browsers, it just uses `document.querySelectorAll()` under the covers, but on older browsers it uses an equivalent (but much slower) method to do the same thing.

Comment: IE8 supports querySelector/querySelectorAll methods.

Comment: Good point. See this [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) for details.

Comment: Saying "most people" is a little misguiding. The majority of people that are using jQuery, may not be using it for the reasons you've described (legacy support).

Comment: If you don't need all of the jQuery goodies, you can check out [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), the selector engine behind jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Scimonster, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't strictly answer your question, but if you use jQuery you can select elements using css selectors. So for your example you would write:

```
$('.selector p').css({color: 'red'});
```